# problem with updating metabox of upload image

Tags: images, metabox, uploads

I created a custom post type and metabox for uploading another image. the problem is when i add the image its shown correctly in its place in backend and when i update its also the same i had the image displayed.

But when i get back to the the post to modify it i can't find the picture and if i make an update to the post so there is no picture to be displayed.

```
<?php   
function hotels_meta_boxes() {
add_meta_box( 'hotels_form', 'Hotels - Détails', 'hotels_form', 'hotels', 'normal', 'high' );} function hotels_form() {
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$hotel_data = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_hotel', true );
$carte = ( empty( $hotel_data['carte'] ) ) ? '' : $hotel_data['carte'];
wp_nonce_field( 'hotels', 'hotels' );
?>  
    <h2 class="metaboxtitle">Coordonnées</h2>
<?php 
    global $post;

    $image_src = '';

    $image_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_hotel', true );
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id );

    ?>
    <img id="book_image" src="<?php echo $image_src ?>" style="max-width:100%;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hotel[carte]" id="upload_image_id" value="<?php echo $image_id; ?>" />

        <a title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Set book image' ) ?>" href="#" id="set-book-image"><?php _e( 'Set book image' ) ?></a>
        <a title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Remove book image' ) ?>" href="#" id="remove-book-image" style="<?php echo ( ! $image_id ? 'display:none;' : '' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Remove book image' ) ?></a>
    </p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        // save the send_to_editor handler function
        window.send_to_editor_default = window.send_to_editor;

        $('#set-book-image').click(function(){

            // replace the default send_to_editor handler function with our own
            window.send_to_editor = window.attach_image;
            tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id=<?php echo $post->ID ?>&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');

            return false;
        });

        $('#remove-book-image').click(function() {

            $('#upload_image_id').val('');
            $('img').attr('src', '');
            $(this).hide();

            return false;
        });

        // handler function which is invoked after the user selects an image from the gallery popup.
        // this function displays the image and sets the id so it can be persisted to the post meta
        window.attach_image = function(html) {

            // turn the returned image html into a hidden image element so we can easily pull the relevant attributes we need
            $('body').append('<div id="temp_image">' + html + '</div>');

            var img = $('#temp_image').find('img');

            imgurl   = img.attr('src');
            imgclass = img.attr('class');
            imgid    = parseInt(imgclass.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);

            $('#upload_image_id').val(imgid);
            $('#remove-book-image').show();

            $('img#book_image').attr('src', imgurl);
            try{tb_remove();}catch(e){};
            $('#temp_image').remove();

            // restore the send_to_editor handler function
            window.send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor_default;

        }

    });
    </script>

</p>
<?php } add_action( 'save_post', 'hotels_save_post' );/*** Data validation and saving** This functions is attached to the 'save_post' action hook.*/ function hotels_save_post( $post_id ) {
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;

if ( ! empty( $_POST['hotels'] ) && ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['hotels'], 'hotels' ) )
    return;

if ( ! empty( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return;
} else {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
}

if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && 'hotels' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'hotels_save_post' );

    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
    ) );

    add_action( 'save_post', 'hotels_save_post' );
}

if ( ! empty( $_POST['hotel'] ) ) {
    $hotel_data['carte'] = ( empty( $_POST['hotel']['carte'] ) ) ? '' : sanitize_text_field( $_POST['hotel']['carte'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_hotel', $hotel_data );
} else {
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_hotel' );
}} add_filter( 'manage_edit-hotels_columns', 'hotels_edit_columns' );/******************** and to show it i use *************************/if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $hotel_data = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_hotel', true );
        $carte = ( empty( $hotel_data['carte'] ) ) ? '' : $hotel_data['carte'];
        $hotels .= '<div class="hotel_map">';
                $carte = ( empty( $hotel_data['carte'] ) ) ? 'Map introuvable' : $hotel_data['carte'];
            $hotels .= '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $carte ) . '" style="margin-top: 10px;"/>' ;
            $hotels .= '</div>';//fin map
            endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
else {
    echo 'Pas d\'hotels pour l\'instant';
}
return $hotels;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no time to write at your code, but with your help works for me

```
function wms_add_headerimage_cb( $post ){
//campuri
$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

$headerpageimage        = isset( $values['headerpageimage'][0] ) ? esc_attr( $values['headerpageimage'][0] ) : '';
$img_src                = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $headerpageimage, 'medium' );

wp_nonce_field( 'allpages_meta_box', 'allpages_meta_box_nonce' );
?>
    <p>
        <img id="headerpage_image" src="<?php echo $img_src[0] ?>" style="max-width:100%;" />
        <input type="hidden" name="headerpageimage" id="headerpageimage" value="<?php echo $headerpageimage; ?>" />

    <a title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Set image' ) ?>" href="#" id="set-book-image"><?php _e( 'Set image' ) ?></a>
    <a title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Remove image' ) ?>" href="#" id="remove-headerpageimage" style="<?php echo ( ! $headerpageimage ? 'display:none;' : '' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Remove image' ) ?></a>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // save the send_to_editor handler function
    window.send_to_editor_default = window.send_to_editor;

    $('#set-book-image').click(function(){

        // replace the default send_to_editor handler function with our own
        window.send_to_editor = window.attach_image;
        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id=<?php echo $post->ID ?>&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');

        return false;
    });

    $('#remove-headerpageimage').click(function() {

        $('#headerpageimage').val('');
        $('img').attr('src', '');
        $(this).hide();

        return false;
    });

    // handler function which is invoked after the user selects an image from the gallery popup.
    // this function displays the image and sets the id so it can be persisted to the post meta
    window.attach_image = function(html) {

        // turn the returned image html into a hidden image element so we can easily pull the relevant attributes we need
        $('body').append('<div id="temp_image">' + html + '</div>');

        var img = $('#temp_image').find('img');

        imgurl   = img.attr('src');
        imgclass = img.attr('class');
        imgid    = parseInt(imgclass.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);

        $('#headerpageimage').val(imgid);
        $('#remove-headerpageimage').show();

        $('img#headerpage_image').attr('src', imgurl);
        try{tb_remove();}catch(e){};
        $('#temp_image').remove();

        // restore the send_to_editor handler function
        window.send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor_default;

    }

});
</script>
<?php
```

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'headerimage_save' );
function headerimage_save( $post_id ){

```
if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;
if( !isset( $_POST['allpages_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['allpages_meta_box_nonce'], 'allpages_meta_box' ) ) return $post_id;    
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return $post_id;  
$allowed = array(   
    'a' => array( // on allow a tags  
        'href' => array() // and those anchors can only have href attribute  
    )  
);

// quantity Icon
if( isset( $_POST['headerpageimage'] ) )  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'headerpageimage', esc_attr( $_POST['headerpageimage']) );
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i didn't get exactly what you wanna say (why did you create a function).

I left the first part as it was and i added this lines to my code .

$allowed = array(   
    'a' => array( // on allow a tags  
        'href' => array() // and those anchors can only have href attribute  
    )  
);

// quantity Icon
if( isset( $_POST['upload_image_id'] ) )  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'upload_image_id', esc_attr( $_POST['upload_image_id']) );

I used the id of hidden input on it, is that true??

but nothing changed after updating, i can't find the image on his place again.